# Defining bijective function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ is countable set using cantor first diagonal method: [image]

where every-time we count the elemnts on the digonal with the direction of the arrow ($(1,1)\mapsto1,(2,1)\mapsto 2,(1,2)\mapsto3,(3,1)\mapsto4$ etc). I know that if I had same problem with $\mathbb N \cup{0}\times \mathbb N \cup{0}$ I could define cantor's function by $f(x,y)=\frac {(x+y+1)(x+y)}{2}+y$  which I'm not sure its' bijective. How can I define a function according to my scheme?

**EDIT:** The question is NOT about proving $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ is countable but on writing appropriate bijective function for the described diagonal method.

Comment: Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278679/does-anyone-know-a-closed-form-expression-for-a-bijection-between-mathbbnk/278692#278692.

Comment: Can you not compose the function you know for $\mathbb N \cup{0}\times \mathbb N \cup{0}$ with a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N \cup{0}$?

Comment: To be more specific than copper.hat, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/278692/43351) to the linked question (incidentally by copper.hat). $\beta^{-1}$ is the function you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Say $X$ and $Y$ are countable, then consider $f : X \times Y \to \mathbb{N}$ be given by

$$f(x,y) = 2^x3^y $$

Prove this is injective.

Comment: What is $f^{-1}(5)$? Your function is only an injection.

Comment: injectivity is enough to show a set $X$ is countable